# Parse entire directory Etree Parse lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree, jupyter

I need to parse txt files with xml markup in a directory (I already created a corpus with glob), yet etree parse only allows one file at a time. How do I set up a loop to parse all files at once? The goal then is to add these files to Elasticsearch using requests. This is what I have so far:

```
import json
import os
import re
from lxml import etree
import xmltodict 
import glob

corpus=glob.glob('path/*.txt')
ns=dict(tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0")
tree = etree.ElementTree(file='path/file.txt')
doc = {
    "author": tree.xpath('//tei:author/text()', namespaces=ns)[0],
    "title": tree.xpath('//tei:title/text()', namespaces=ns)[0],
    "content": "".join(tree.xpath('//tei:text/text()', namespaces=ns))
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate on the `corpus` list. However, you will want to use a container such as a list or dictionary to hold the individually parsed data. Below assumes .txt files are well-formed .xml files and maintain same structure including `tei` namespace:

```
import os, glob
from lxml import etree

corpus = glob.glob('path/*.txt')
ns = dict(tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0")

xmlList = []; xmlDict = {}

for file in corpus:
    tree = etree.parse(file)
    doc = {
           "author": tree.xpath('//tei:author/text()', namespaces=ns)[0],
           "title": tree.xpath('//tei:title/text()', namespaces=ns)[0],
           "content": "".join(tree.xpath('//tei:text/text()', namespaces=ns))
          }
    # LIST OF DOC DICTS
    xmlList.append(doc)                

    # DICTIONARY OF DOC DICTS, KEY IS FILE NAME
    key = os.path.basename(file).replace('.txt', '')
    xmlDict[key] = doc
```